# Menu listing in Python

Tags: python, list, mean, median

I am very very new to Python so I apologize in advance! I am trying to create a list where the user has the option to add a number, display the mean, display the median, print the list in order, print the list in reverse order, or quit. I thought I was on the right track but I cant get it to run. Can anyone help me?

```
def main():
    myList = [ ]
    addOne(myList)
    choice = displayMenu()
    while choice != '6':
        if choice == '1':
            addOne(myList)
        elif choice == '2':
            mean(myList)
        elif choice == '3':
            median(myList)
        elif choice == '4':
             print(myList)
        elif choice == '5':
            print(myList)
        choice = displayMenu()

    print ("\nThanks for playing!\n\n")

def displayMenu():
    myChoice = '0'
    while myChoice != '1' and myChoice != '2' \
              and myChoice != '3' \
              and myChoice != '4' and myChoice != '5':
        print("""\n\nPlease choose
                1. Add a number to the list/array
                2. Display the mean
                3. Display the median
                4. Print the list/array to the screen
                5. Print the list/array in reverse order
                6. Quit
                """)
        myChoice = input("Enter option---> ")
        if myChoice != '1' and myChoice != '2' and \
           myChoice != '3' and myChoice != '4' and myChoice != '5':
            print("Invalid option. Please select again.")

    return myChoice

#This should make sure that the user puts in a correct input
def getNum():
    num = -1
    while num < 0:
        num = int(input("\n\nEnter a non-negative integer: "))
        if num < 0:
            print("Invalid value. Please re-enter.")

    return num

#This is to take care of number one on the list: Add number
def addOne(theList):
    while True:
        try:
            num = (int(input("Give me a number:")))
            num = int(num)
            if num < 0:
                raise exception
            print("Thank you!")
            break
        except:
            print("Invalid. Try again...")
        theList.append(num)


#This should take care of the second on the list: Mean       
def mean(theList):
    myList = []
    listSum = sum(myList)
    listLength = len(myList)
    listMean = listSum / listLength
    print("The mean is", listMean)

#This will take care of number three on the list: Median
def median(theList):
    myList = []
    return myList.median(theList.array(myList))
    print("The median is", listMedian)


#This will take care of the fourth thing on the list: Print the list 
def sort(theList):
    theList.sort()
    print(theList) 

#This will take care of the fifth thing on the list
def reversesort(theList):
    theList.sort(reverse=True)
    print(theList)


main()
```

When I try to choose option 2 it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Gunter/Documents/CS 110/List and Traversal and Exception        Handling.py", line 94, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Gunter/Documents/CS 110/List and Traversal and Exception   Handling.py", line 12, in main
    mean(myList)
  File "/Users/Gunter/Documents/CS 110/List and Traversal and Exception   Handling.py", line 73, in mean
    listMean = listSum / listLength
ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

When I try to run the third option it gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Gunter/Documents/CS 110/List and Traversal and Exception  Handling.py", line 94, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/Gunter/Documents/CS 110/List and Traversal and Exception Handling.py", line 14, in main
    median(myList)
  File "/Users/Gunter/Documents/CS 110/List and Traversal and Exception Handling.py", line 79, in median
    return myList.median(theList.array(myList))
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'median'
```

Comment: You need to be more specific than "I can't get it to run".

Comment: I have tried copy/pasting this and there's a few things undefined. What is the issue you are having? Should this be a self-contained example?

Comment: If I try to choose the option of calculating the mean or calculating the median it blows up. If I try to choose the option print the list either in order or in reverse it just shows an empty set.

Comment: If code "blows up" it usually gives a handy trail of errors in a traceback. Can you please include it in your question as an edit? Without even running the code, my editor is showing `listMedian` as undefined in `median()`, so I know that will fail to run.

Comment: I just posted what it says when I try to run the mean and median. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: So instantly the traceback can answer the first point. In `mean()` you have `myList = []` i.e. an empty list of zero length and then you try to divide by the length of that list. You cannot divide by zero, as the error is showing. You probably want to change `listLength = len(myList)` to `listLength = len(theList)`. Pay attention to the traceback.

Comment: When I try that it seems to give me the exact same errors.

Comment: `median()` has quite a number of mistakes. Look at the traceback. Google the error. What is it supposed to be doing and why do you think it's not working? Already there's one abnormality in common with `mean()`. It's far better for you to try think the problem through than have someone answer for things like this; you're going to need to do this a **lot** going forwards. Use "@roganjosh" in your comment to reply to me when you think you have an answer.

Comment: Also, `AttributeError` and `ZeroDivisionError` are not the same errors.

Comment: Please see [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Answer (score 1):

## Problem with mean

You got a really good hint from the traceback message: `ZeroDivisionError: division by zero`. What was the denominator of your division? `listLength`. Where was `listLength` calculated from? The length of an empty list (`myList`) that you created with local scope to the function. You needed the length of the list passed as an argument to the function instead.

There's another problem with your mean calculation also: your numerator isn't correct for the division either. Fixing it is left as an exercise to you.

## Problem with median

Again, the traceback message gave you a really good hint: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'median'`. Neither the [common sequence operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-list-tuple-range) nor the [List-type operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#lists) provide a `median` method. You either need to define it as a function or build a class that defines it as a class method and has a List as internal storage.

Or, you could avoid re-inventing the wheel -- probably the most Pythonic answer of all -- and use the [`statistics`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/statistics.html) module from the standard library.